# VLC media player: hotkeys to change size of subtitle font

Tags: vlc

`VLC media player 3.0.18 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)`

`Linux 6.1.3-arch1-1`

I want to increase/decrease the size of the subtitle font using *keys*. The default setting requires the mouse wheel which with my settings is impossible to adjust with sufficiently fine increments. With the smallest adjustment I get subtitles filling the screen or too tiny to read.

I don't see the setting in the the `Tools.Preferences.HotKeys` dialog. The only subtitle options that I see there are for synchronisation.

uPDATE:

There is a text configuration file `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc` that has the following subtitle references that suggest sizing:

```
#global-key-subtitle-text-scale-normal=
# Reset subtitles text scale (string)
#key-subtitle-text-scale-normal=Ctrl+0
# Scale down subtitles text (string)
#global-key-subtitle-text-scale-up=
# Scale down subtitles text (string)
key-subtitle-text-scale-up=Ctrl+Mouse Wheel Up
# Scale up subtitles text (string)
#global-key-subtitle-text-scale-down=
# Scale up subtitles text (string)
key-subtitle-text-scale-down=Ctrl+Mouse Wheel Down
```

I have tried changing the `scale-up/down` settings ( using Mouse ) to for example `Ctrl+G` `Ctrl+K` following the format for setting `key-subtitle-text-scale-normal`, but though I see no error, it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me on VLC 3.0.18 on Debian 11, you only need a lowercase `g` and `k`:

```
$ grep key-subtitle-text ~/.config/vlc/vlcrc
#global-key-subtitle-text-scale-normal=
#key-subtitle-text-scale-normal=Ctrl+0
#global-key-subtitle-text-scale-up=
key-subtitle-text-scale-up=Ctrl+g
#global-key-subtitle-text-scale-down=
key-subtitle-text-scale-down=Ctrl+k
```

I changed them initially in the hotkeys dialog (search for "sub"), but editing the config works as well:

[image: screenshot hotkeys dialog]

Comment: Ah right. I didn't see those options in the dialog. Thanks.